# How to schedule profile based on time?

Tags: android

In my project I want to schedule the audio profile based on time.
In which starting and ending time of scheduling is receive from user and that data is store in SQLite db.
I done All this things.
I create Intent Service class to gain the current time.
In service class I fetch the time which is stored in database and compare it with the current time. If both matches then I check the profile mode given by user and according to that I use AudioManager class to change the mode.
But scheduling is not done.

```
int HF1,MF1,HT1,MT1;
                        String hf1,mf1,ht1,mt1,profile1;
                        hf1="";
                        mf1="";
                        ht1="";
                        mt1="";
                        profile1="";
                        String hf,mf,ht,mt;
                        Intent intentF1S=new Intent(getBaseContext(),SilentBroadcast.class);
                        final PendingIntent senderF1S=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intentF1S, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 


                        Intent intentT1S=new Intent(getBaseContext(),NormalBroadcast.class);
                        final PendingIntent senderT1S=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intentT1S, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 


                        Intent intentF1V=new Intent(getBaseContext(),VibrateBroadcast.class);
                        final PendingIntent senderF1V=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intentF1V, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 


                        Intent intentT1V=new Intent(getBaseContext(),NormalBroadcast.class);
                        final PendingIntent senderT1V=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, intentT1V, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 


                        mHelper=new DbHelper(getBaseContext());
                        mHelper.open();
                        Cursor c=mHelper.returnDatat();
                        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                hf1=(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_HFROM)));
                                mf1=(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_MFROM)));
                                ht1=(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_HTO)));
                                mt1=(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_MTO)));
                                profile1=(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_PROFILE)));

                                try
                                {
                                    HF1=Integer.parseInt(hf1.toString());
                                    HT1=Integer.parseInt(ht1.toString());

                                    MF1=Integer.parseInt(mf1.toString());
                                    MT1=Integer.parseInt(mt1.toString());

                            Calendar cf1=Calendar.getInstance();
                            cf1.set(Calendar.HOUR, HF1);
                            cf1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MF1);


                            Calendar ct1=Calendar.getInstance();
                            ct1.set(Calendar.HOUR, HT1);
                            ct1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MT1);




                             if(profile1.contains("Silent"))
                             {
                                AlarmManager amf1=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                amf1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cf1.getTimeInMillis(), senderF1S);

                                AlarmManager amt1=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                amt1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ct1.getTimeInMillis(), senderT1S);


                             }
                             else if(profile1.contains("Vibrate"))
                             {

                                AlarmManager amf1=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                amf1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cf1.getTimeInMillis(), senderF1V);

                                AlarmManager amt1=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                amt1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ct1.getTimeInMillis(), senderT1V);

                             }

                             else
                             {
                                AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                                am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                             }
                            }


                            }catch(Exception e)
                            {

                            }



                    }while (c.moveToNext());


                mHelper.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a Alarm Manager for this Task. set a Repeat Alarm for 24 Hour. and update the alarm manager when user update lets suppose user set starting is 6.00 am then 6.00 am alarm manager notify you that now you can start. It saves you with lots of trouble deal with service. and unwanted comparison of checking the time with current time. I hope It will help you! have a great Day!

Comment: I do this thing also

Comment: In my Service class I fetch the value of profile then acording to value of profile I call the Appropriate AlaramManger class. But it also fail to schedule.